# (React Native/Android) Android getFilesDir() gives me '/data/user/' instead of '/data/data/'

Tags: java, android, react-native

I am building an app which has a feature to crop images using `react-native-image-crop-picker`. I am trying to implement the logic to store the cropped images locally in my react native app. I could successfully implement the logic for iOS, however, I am having trouble with the Android side.

My problem is that when I store the image using `reactContext.getFilesDir()`, the image is stored into the `/data/user/0/com.myapp/files/` directory. And the images can be accessed via 'Google Photos' app or 'Files' app. I don't want to let the users access these images.

Here is the picture describing my problem.
[image]

**The things I have tried so far:**
1. Use `getCurrentActivity()` instead of `reactContext`
2. Use `getReactApplicationContext()` instead of `context`

**Findings:**
- After saving the image, it is stored into `/data/user/0/com.myapp/files/`, `/data/data/0/com.myapp/files/` and `storage/emulated/0/Pictures/`.

FileStreamHandler.java

```
public class FileStreamHandler extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
  private Context context;
//  private Activity mActivity;

  @Nonnull
  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return "FileStreamHandler";
  }

  public FileStreamHandler(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    super(reactContext);
//    mActivity = reactContext.getCurrentActivity();
    this.context = reactContext;
  }

  @ReactMethod
  private void saveImageData(String base64String, Callback callback) {
    // Generate random image name
    String fileName = UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".png";
//    File fileDirectory = mActivity.getFilesDir();
    File fileDirectory = context.getFilesDir();

    File imageFile = new File(fileDirectory, fileName);
    String imageFilePath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();

    try {
      OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);

      //decode base64 string to image
      byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decode(base64String, Base64.DEFAULT);
      Bitmap decodedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedBytes, 0, decodedBytes.length);

      decodedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, stream);
      stream.flush();
      stream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    callback.invoke(imageFilePath);
  }
}
```

The image is stored successfully without any errors. However, it is stored into `/data/user/` and can be accessed via other applications such as 'Photos' or 'Files'.

Although I am using exactly the same logic in my pure Android app, I have never had this problem. Therefore, I am suspecting that the react application context is causing the problem.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: "Since it is stored into that directory, the images can be accessed via 'Google Photos' app or 'Files' app" -- that directory is not accessible by either app.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I didn't know that. However, when I open up these apps, I can see that there are images which are stored by my react native app.

Comment: That is possible, but they are in a different directory than what you cited and were created by different code than what you have here. Depending on where you are seeing these files, you may be using things like `getExternalFilesDir()`, `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`, or `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`. Your code here is putting the files on internal storage, which is not visible to users (outside of perhaps rooted devices).

Comment: Hmm.. this is kind of a weird behavior since I am not using any methods such as `getExternalFilesDir()`, `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` or `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`. When I print out `fileDirectory .getAbsolutePath()`, I just see `/data/user/0/com.myapp/files/filename.png` in my console.

Comment: Delete the files that you are seeing using the Files app. Then, re-run your code. If the files return, then something must be copying them from where you are writing them to their final destination. If the files do not return, then perhaps they were from some previous run of your app.

Comment: I can delete the images using the Photos app and the images do not return. When I re-run my app and save some images again, however, newly saved images show up in the same place even after re-running the code...

Comment: Where is "the same place"? If you use the Files app, or Device File Explorer in Android Studio, where are you finding these files?

Comment: I found that the images are still alive in the `data/user/0/com.myapp/files/` directory even after I deleted the images using the Photos app. However, they are removed from the Photos app or Files app.

Comment: That would suggest that you are deleting a copy of the files. I don't use React-Native, so I don't know if they are doing some sort of content copying.

Comment: At least, I could learn that the path is not the cause of the problem. I will check to see if my RN code is generating unwanted copies of the images or not. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the cause of the problem is the react native library that I am using. I don't know why they implemented in this way, however, it seems like the `react-native-image-crop-picker` library saves images into the `/storage/0/Pictures/` directory after cropping.